# Incompatibilty between hyperref and FourierOrns?

Tags: hyperref, luatex, fourier

Consider this file to be compiled with lualatex or xelatex:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fourier-otf}
%\usepackage[pdftitle={My title},pdfauthor={Me}]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\textpertenthousand,           \textit{\textpertenthousand},
\textbf{\textpertenthousand},  \textbf{\textit{\textpertenthousand}}.

\eurologo, \textit{\eurologo},
\textbf{\eurologo},  \textbf{\textit{\eurologo}}.
\end{document}
```

The output is as expected:

[image]

Now, if I uncomment the hyperref line, I get

[image]

What is going wrong? thanks!

Comment: the percent characters are supposed to be encoding-specific commands but the Fourier package defines it to `\TakeFourierOrnament {37}` but hyperref resets the original encoding specific version so that it can define behaviour for its puenc PDF encoding

Comment: simplest is to load fourier-otf after hyperref

Comment: `\DeclareTextCommand\textpertenthousand{TU}{\TakeFourierOrnament{37}}` after fourier-otf is better, it won't break the usage in the bookmarks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fourier-otf` redefines `\textpercentthousand` with a fixed definition so losing its original encoding-specific definition. So when `hyperref` adds a definition for its own PU encoding, the defintion for the main text encoding is lost.

A simple workaround is to correct the definition after loading fourier

```
\DeclareTextCommand{\textpertenthousand}{TU}{\TakeFourierOrnament{37}}
```

But a correct fix would be to change `fourier-otf.sty` at line 22 to use `\DeclareTextCommand` not `\renewcommand`:

```
$ diff fourier-orns.sty~ fourier-orns.sty
22c22
<   \renewcommand*{\textpertenthousand}{\TakeFourierOrnament{37}}
---
>   \DeclareTextCommand{\textpertenthousand}{TU}{\TakeFourierOrnament{37}}
```

You could report it to the package maintainer.

Comment: actually fourier-orns should check all its symbols for compability with the bookmarks, if needed it should use \texorpdfstring to provide a sensible unicode replacement.